# How do I remove the gap between these two div sections?

Tags: html, css

My HTML code looks a bit like this, and for some reason it keeps misaligning or inserting an uncontrollable gap.

```
<section id="boxes">

<div id="boxes1">
<ul>
<li>Justs the Facts</li>            
</ul>
</div>

<div id="boxes2">
<ul>
<li>Visit Neptune</li>
</ul>
</div>

</section>
```

The relevant CSS is here:

```
#boxes {
  width:700px;
  background-color: #ffffff
}
#boxes1 {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
}
#boxes2 {
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
}
```

This creates something like two blocks, with a gap in between. How could I create it so that there's no margin or gap between the div section of `boxes1` versus `boxes2`?

Comment: `margin: 0` on the ULs

Comment: Just realise that there is no gap between divs. Just that the UL takes more space in each div than you expected

Answer (score 2):

Use this for both boxes.

```
.boxes {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it causes list elements to be sequentially processed. See: http://jsfiddle.net/wBjZw/12/

Comment: You can still float in different directions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are floating your `div` elements in opposite directions.

```
#boxes1 {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
}
#boxes2 {
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
}
```

Float both of them to the left.

```
#boxes1, #boxes2 {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're floating one to the right. This makes the div align to the right of the containing div or the body.

You should use float:left on both.

Like so:

```
#boxes{
 width:700px;
 background-color: #ffffff
  }
#boxes1{
 width: 350px;
 float: left; }
#boxes2 {
width: 350px;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must float two boxes to the same direction, right or left.

```
#boxes1{
width: 350px;
float: left; /*or right*/ }
#boxes2 {
width: 350px;
float: left; /*or right*/ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the needful.

```
#boxes{
 width:700px;
 background-color: #ffffff
  }
#boxes1{
 width: 350px;
 float: left; 
 }
#boxes2 {
width: 350px;
float: left;

}
```

You can check it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wBjZw/

Comment: There's a margin in front of the li element, for example, in front of "Visit Neptune" from the blue "Just the facts". How would I remove that?

Comment: Just add this:
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}

Comment: Then mark the answer as r8. so that others can benifit from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#boxes1{
width: 50%;
float: left;
#boxes2 {
width: 50%;
float: left; 
}
```

Try this...

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
#boxes ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```